# \SetKeys (ltkeys): property '.default' is unknown?

Tags: key-value

Reading 'source2e.dtx' suggests that the 'l3keys' property '.default' should be available.  The following MWE doesn't work as I expected though:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand*{\test}[1]{\textcolor{\mycolor}{#1}}

\DeclareKeys{
   ref.default = red        ,
   ref.store   = \mycolor   ,
  }

\begin{document}

\SetKeys{
  ref = blue,
  }
\test{Blue}

\SetKeys{
  ref,
  }
\test{Red}
\end{document}
```

I get an error [TeXLive 2023 updated today]:

"./DeclareKey.tex:9: LaTeX Error: The key property '.default' is unknown."

and The "Red" text is printed in black (I expected red).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The key property to set a default value doesn't have a LaTeX2e equivalent (yet?), you'll have to use `.default:n` instead for now (see the documentation of the `l3keys`-module in `interface3.pdf`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand*{\test}[1]{\textcolor{\mycolor}{#1}}

\DeclareKeys{
   ref.store   = \mycolor   ,
   ref.default:n = red        ,
  }

\begin{document}

\SetKeys{
  ref = blue,
  }
\test{Blue}

\SetKeys{
  ref,
  }
\test{Red}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this clarification!